# Suggestion to encourage people on positive criticism upon downvoting

Tags: feature-request

Similar to this [suggestion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/feature-request-downvote-popup-to-provide-anonymous-feedback), I often see questions or answers that are downvoted without any or hardly any explanation. Often, I believe the questioner or answerer may simply not be as well-versed both in Judaism and in how MY works, making entirely anonymous downvotes pointless - is this site not a place for learning and sharing of Jewish knowledge?

Therefore, I thought of suggesting to add a window to the side-bar reminding everyone that not all users were born with a proper Jewish education and that MY is a place for learning, etc, and positive criticism would be very helpful, or something along those lines.

Comment: This topic is recurring in different forms. The problem is that stack exchange has his own habits and the same habits are present in MY. Jewish education is often skipped. But most users are really fair. You don't have to give importance to the few users who downvote without explanation

Comment: @kouty it seemed common to me, but if you say it's not that common, then maybe I'm wrong.